Added file from a location other than the curren project's adds a '<other locations>' section in the project view which cannot be removed
On Windows, using Qt Creator 14.0.1, I added a file (by right clicking > Add exisiting file, in the project view), and it opened up a <Other Locations> file. I cannot seem to remove it.
How do I remove the <Other locations> section?  The <Other Locations> folder contains a file from another project.

Tried removing the directory by right-clicking on the file -> Remove file.

Well, the file is indeed in another location, so isn't it intuitive to be classified as such? Where else would you like it to appear? The only option I know about would be to "Simplify Tree".
